# Reading deserialized xml file - class with one array for values

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-deserialization

I need to create/read xml file. I got an .xsd file, and generated .cs class. Serialization and deserialization works. When I'm creating file I simply add value to Items array and type to ItemsElementName array.

The problem is with reading. In class there aren't properties like Date, Header etc., but there is only one array in which you store objects and second array in which you store types.

Usually, when I need to read an xml file, I deserialize it and get an instance with objects in it, but in this situation it isn't that simple. I have only one array full of values and it is hard to get the values i need.

```
public partial class Invoice
{

    private object[] itemsField;

    public Invoice()
    {
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Dates", typeof(Dates))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Header", typeof(Header))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("CompanyData", typeof(CompanyData))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("TextDescription", typeof(TextDescription))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("InvoiceItems", typeof(InvoiceItems))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute("ItemsElementName")]
    public object[] Items
    {
        get
        {
            return this.itemsField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.itemsField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ItemsElementName")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public ItemsChoiceType1[] ItemsElementName
    {
        get
        {
            return this.itemsElementNameField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.itemsElementNameField = value;
        }
    }

// etc ...
}
```

Class Header again has one array for values, and second for types (types can be string and user defined like InvoiceType...).

Currently, I tried two solutions. In first I deserialized xml file and iterated through Items array. But this isn't so simple, because in one array I have values, and in second are types.

In second I stayed away from deserialization and used XDocument and got the values I need.

Is there any better solution?

Comment: I'm not quite clear what you problem is.  If you have a Xsd that you need to read/write from and you can do it then what exactly is your problem?

Comment: when i deserialize file I get two arrays full of values (first array with values and second with types). it is hard for me to get the values i want from this array(s). so i wonder is there better solution? for example, XDocument looks much more simpler for now

Comment: Maybe you can post the Xsd and a sample of the incoming Xml.  Is it true that you cannot change the Xsd and Xml format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could manually define your classes, for instance

```
public partial class Invoice
{
    public Invoice()
    {
    }

    [XmlElement("Dates")]
    public List<Dates> Dates { get; set; }

    // and so on.
}
```

It's really not that difficult, a few minutes and you are done and they can be deserialized by `XmlSerializer` in a more convenient manner.

Alternatively, you could use Lambda expressions + extension methods to pick out the required information, for instance:

```
public static class InvoiceExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<Dates> Dates(this Invoice invoice)
    {
        return invoice.Items.OfType<Dates>();
    }
}
```

The objects in the `Items` table are actually of the expected types, you just need to filter them out.  The only time you really *need* to use the `ItemsElementName` is when different choices (i.e. different XML element names) map to the *same* data type, and you need know which was which. In cases like that, you could use [Enumerable.Zip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd267698%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to put them together:

```
public static class InvoiceExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<ItemsChoiceType1, object>> ElementNamesAndItems<T>(this Invoice invoice)
    {
        return invoice.ItemsElementName.Zip(invoice.Items, (choice, item) => new KeyValuePair<ItemsChoiceType1, object>(choice, item)).Where(p => p.Value is T);
    }
}
```

And then later filter them:

```
var relevantDates = invoice.ElementNamesAndItems<Dates>().Where(p => p.Key == ItemsChoiceType1.StartDate).Select(p => p.Value);
```

This might not be necessary in your case since it appears each of your choices corresponds to a different class.